# Schematics: Capacitor

Tags: capacitor, schematics

Wondering if someone could explain what the 1 and 2 mean when placed by each capacitor on this snipit from a schematic.  Tried to use Google without success.

[image]

Comment: The pcb footprint has two pads - 1 and 2. Whilst the capacitor is not polarised, it still has two connections that correspond with the pcb footprint.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put these are just the pin numbers of the component.

On a simple 2 pin non-polarized component they are normally of no use to someone reading the schematic. Most CAD software programs will even allow the designer to disable the display of these numbers.  However when a component is polarized or has multiple pins (for eg. an IC) the pin numbers are obviously much more important.

When a schematic component is designed using a CAD program every pin needs to have a designation.  Similarly when a PCB component pattern is designed each physical pin (pcb pad) will have a designation. When the schematic design is later converted to a PCB design the schematic pin numbers are matched up to same pin numbers of the component's PCB pattern.